# Java HashMap Get Highest 3 Values and their Key

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am making a program that keeps a list of users and `Integer` values in a `HashMap`.  I need to loop through the `HashMap`, and get the three highest values.  I also need to get corresponding key of those three values.

> For example - HashMap with values:
>
> User1: 13
>
> User2: 325
>
> User3: 1
>
> User4: 456
>
> User5: 666

**Would give me:**

> User5
>
> User4
>
> User2
>
> (In that order)

Comment: What if multiple keys have the same values?

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?!

Comment: I'm glad you have made so much effort so far. :) You could sort the map, which would be the most promising approach in my opinion.

Comment: @tbrown - maps can't be sorted. However, you can sort the entry set.

Comment: @TedHopp true enough, I wasn't suggesting to use a `sort()` method, but rather to search for "How to sort a map". I haven't sorted a map either until half a year ago and it wasn't hard to figure out (or find) a working solution. ;)

Comment: 1st Comment - That's a problem I've been wondering about...how do you keep them paired...but I guess it wouldn't really matter.

Comment: 2nd Comment - I've tried splitting into two lists, but then I can't re-match them together.